# LocalDB Help using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sql-server-2008-r2

It is possible to create the database using SQL Server 2008 R2, once created with all tables and stored procedures etc. then copy and paste it into the Visual Studio `App_Data` folder to be used as localdb?

I found that is very tedious creating the database with tables and stored procedure using the Visual Studio project.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 has been formally end of life for several years now. That means it hasn't received any updates -- **NOT EVEN CRITICAL SECURITY PATCHES** -- in a very long time, and there are multiple open critical-rated CVE's that will NEVER be patched. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using this.

Comment: Why bother or even risk local db? Your at deployment time in near all cases will need a running instance of SQL server, and localdb will not work without as such in most cases anyway. Little reason to use local db, and it really only is a solution for existing templates, and saves a small amount of setup time, and in most cases not much at all. For local development, install free edition of SQL express. That way, you can be FAR MORE sure that when you deploy to production, everything going to work.

Comment: You can't use localDB in a production site and it does not even support multi-user options correctly anyway. Don't bother with localDB - you just wasting  your time.

Comment: Thank you, Albert, for your reply. The reason I mentioned SQL 2008 R2 was for back compatibility, I've found that a few asp.net hosting still using SQL 2008, SQL 2012, and SQL 2016 etc. How about using with WinForm would that be OK?

Comment: @AlDiz A web host still using 2008 R2 is a host worth avoiding.

Answer (score 2):

You can (sort of) do this, but SQL Server 2008 R2 is **no longer supported**, has not been supported for a very long time, and recent versions that are still under support are **free** for databases up to 10GB.

In fact, SQL Server 2008 R2 *pre-dates* LocalDB. However, I believe LocalDB can still load a SQL Server 2008 R2 database; it's just the actual service will then be running something newer, but at the 2008 R2 (100) compatibility level.

So assuming you move to an actually-supported version, the process looks like this:

1. Create the database as needed on your server.
2. **Detach** the database from the original server.
3. Copy the associated (now-detached) *.mdf file to the appropriate development location and set the connection string and deployment options you need.

Additionally, for a web project you're almost always better off using Express Edition vs LocalDB anyway.

Comment: up-voted. And 100% agree, Using local db is much for just quick testing, maybe some prototyping. Anything beyond that simple testing, then simple use SQL express, and it will FAR more follow how things will work when you deploy to the production site. Worse yet, is a lot of web hosting systems don't allow one to attach a mdf file to their shared running instances of SQL server anyway.

Comment: Thank you, Joel for your reply. I did not think of detaching then copy would do the job, I was thinking stopping the SQL services then copy the database.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal LocalDB also has a place as a deployment option for single-user applications, but even here I'd tend towards an in-process engine like sqlite or even Access.

Comment: 100% agree, and especially for non web based. These in-process file based systems are a big part of our industry. My point more about the fact this question was tagged with asp.net.   I think for desktop software, stand alone software? yes, such database systems are often a better choice then a server based system (and no install + setup is required). However, this post was tagged as asp.net, and thus the instant web stuff comes into play? I think from the get-go, then a server based system is the better choice.